# Google ads: Is the GT prefixed Google tag the same as the AW one?

Tags: google-ads

In Google Ads, if I go to tools > Google Tag then it shows two Google tag IDs.
One starts with AW- and one with GT-.  The suffix on both is different.

This is a new account, so I've not changed any of this configuration.

My understanding is that the AW- prefix is deprecated, though it seems used throughout the Google Ads admin, including things like the "Install this Google Tag" code snippet.

My question is are these tags functionally the same, and can I use the GT- one instead?

My current assumption is that they're "combined" tags, meaning either will work, but the GT- one will gradually phase out the AW- format, though the prevalence of the AW- tag is making me question this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption about the two tags is correct about being "combined". It's not recommended to use both tags simultaneously. Doing so can create **duplicate** tracking and potentially *skew* your data. Stick to using only the GT- tag for your new account.

Gradual phase-out: Google hasn't officially announced a deadline for retiring the AW- format, but it's safe to assume it will be phased out gradually. Using the GT- tag ensures you're on the right side of this update and avoids any potential disruption in the future.